# Possible to store different vertex attributes and indices in same VBO?

Tags: c++, opengl

(Speaking of OpenGL 3.3) Is there a way to store different vertex attributes in the same VBO? I don't mean interleaved with "stride", I mean for example positions at the beginning of the VBO and texture coordinates at the end of the VBO.

If yes, then is it also true for indices? Can I store vertex indices and vertex attributes in the same VBO and bind it for DrawElements type of draw calls?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, no need for interleaved data.

The last parameter of the gl-command `glVertexAttribPointer()` *"Specifies a offset of the first component of the first generic vertex attribute in the array in the data store of the buffer currently bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target. The initial value is 0."*

Just compute that offset on your own and pass it to the command.

> Can I store vertex indices and vertex attributes in the same VBO and
>   bind it for DrawElements type of draw calls?

If you use different `glVertexAttribPointer` or different `glDrawxx` there's no problem.

What you can't do is reading vertices and indices at the same if they have different type (float vs integer) and stride.

Comment: FYI: ANGLE-based OpenGL implementations (such as you might get from Qt or WebGL implementations) do disallow you from using a buffer object as the source for both vertex and index data. But desktop GL and GL ES have no problem with this.